# How to import a .raw model into blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, export, import

I don't have any experience with Blender. I have a .raw file that contains 3D data. I need to view this as a 3D model, so I decided to import it into Blender then export it as a .off file and view it in Meshlab.

How can I do this? I am importing a .raw file, but it doesn't show anything. Besides, I don't know how to export an .off file.

What am I missing?

Comment: from what software was the `.raw` file produced ? Is it an ascii file that can be opened with a text editor ?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but did you try https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Raw_Mesh_IO?

Comment: also, try to rename the file to .asc extension, and try importing in meshlab directly.

Comment: it is oroduced by VIsual Studio. and it can't be opened by a text editor @R00t

Comment: @m.ardito how should I do that?

Comment: As I wrote, I have no experience with that. But now I see that it is not text data, so it can't be done without specific binary importer, I fear.  Your best chance could be either make VS export in different - non binary - ways, or investigate about the format it used to produce that binary RAW data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a relatively recent version of Blender, did you try opening the User Preferences editor (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>), selecting the "Add-ons" tab, scrolling down to the selection

> Import-Export: Raw mesh format (.raw)

and clicking on the button at the extreme right, to activate the add-on?

Did you then click the <kbd>Save User Settings</kbd> button in the lower left of the editor window to save the activation of the user preferences? If so, then you should be able to open the File menu in the info window, and find the ability to import and export files in ~.raw format in the appropriate sections of the menu.

I don't see where you show the version of Blender you are using in your question, but the add-on has been part of the Blender distribution since at least version 2.63a.

Comment: I tried all things you mentioned and I'm using the latest version of Blender 2.77a